# Equal height of the each product

Tags: html, css

I am using Shopify theme, I am displaying four product in each row. Everything is working perfectly except product column height. I need the equal height of each column. I tried `display: table`the parent class and `display:table-cell` to child class but still not working. Also tried `display:flex`

I am sharing the link to code because of my code huge and not allowing me to upload here.

https://jsfiddle.net/a8ag2270/1/

I am getting the output. I need equal height.
[image]

Comment: as I see you can give min-height to title and description. for the title you can give 2 line min-height and for description 3 line min-height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, that's the best I can do for now.

https://jsfiddle.net/a8ag2270/49/

```
.grid.grid--uniform.grid--view-items {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* had to target more specifically with (div.grid-view-item) */
/* so the margin: 0px auto 35px; gets overridden */
div.grid-view-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0; /* instead of margin: 0px auto 35px; */
}

.grid-view-item__link.grid-view-item__image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

/* same story here */
div.grid-view-item__meta {
  margin-top: auto; /* override margin-top: 8px; */
}
```

It can probably be done with a lot fewer styles (or maybe not), but I like flexboxes and working with them, so I used that.

What you need to do on your own is to set min-height to title, description etc. if you want them to be "aligned horizontally" (can't find the right words for that) with each other.

The above styles put the price down, right above the button. If you don't want that behaviour, you can use this:

```
.grid.grid--uniform.grid--view-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.grid-view-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-view-item__link.grid-view-item__image-container {
  flex: 1;
}
```

or this:

```
.grid.grid--uniform.grid--view-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid__item {
  display: flex;
}

div.grid-view-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.grid-view-item__link.grid-view-item__image-container {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Your code is working perfectly for me. Thank you and upvote for more information.

Comment: I am getting one issue with this code. My al the products are displaying on one line because of display: flex. I added 3 more products and all are displaying in one line. I need first 4 in one row. Please help me in this

Comment: Oops, I forgot about that case. Just style `.grid.grid--uniform.grid--view-items` with `flex-wrap: wrap;`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

add Below code in your css file:

```
#Collection > .grid--view-items
{
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#Collection .grid__item
{
display: flex;
}

#Collection .grid-view-item
{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

#Collection a.grid-view-item__link.grid-view-item__image-container
{ flex: 1 0 0; }
```

Comment: Your code is working 99% for me but not 100% because it's affecting the price. Thank you for your help and upvote from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a style to the `grid-view-item__link` like

```
.grid-view-item__link{
    height:400px;
}
```

Change the 400 to whatever height you want.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cokhm2rj/1/)